# How to integrate Swagger with Maven + Jersey+ jboss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, jersey, jboss7.x, swagger

I have done the code for a jersey REST service for jboss7.2.
below is my REST with swagger anotation. but I can not generate swagger doc for a sample rest service .Can any one help me out to generate rest doc using swagger in detail step by step process

```
    @Api(value="Employee" ,description="manage Emnployee")
@Path("/employee")
public class TestServices {
    @Path("/get/{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value="List all people", notes="List all people using paging")
    public Response getEmployee(@PathParam("id") String empId){
        System.out.println("Employee ID : "+empId);
        Empolyee emp= new Empolyee(empId, "SAnjay");
        return Response.status(200).entity(emp).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with the swagger-core servlet
and point the swagger-ui to where you mapped this servlet.

for Jersey 2.X see: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup#hooking-up-swagger-core-in-your-application

alternatively see : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart

To generage static doc, you need the maven-plugin
https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin

I never had any luck with this one... and I understand the need for static doc generation

I generate static Swagger-UI files using : https://github.com/teamcarma/swagger-jaxrs-doclet with Maven

Also, this project generates the files for the swagger-ui based of JAX-RS annotation and JavaDoc, so no need for Swagger annotations

Comment: I had searched at always but i can't get understand the process , how to mapped with rest ,swagger annotation to static documents.

Comment: you need to add the plugin of your choice to your maven config : pom.xml, and configure it as needed. When you launch the maven build, with the appropriate "goal", the plugin will execute and produce the document where configured. If you launch your maven build from Eclipse, make sure to refresh your target folder (if you configured the plugin to generate them within the target folder)